# 14.04 samba-winbind pam_mkhomedir.so home directory ownership

Tags: home-directory, authentication

After joining ubuntu 14.04 to our Active-Directory Domain using samba-winbind pam_mkhomedir creates home, but ~/.config and other directories are owned by root, preventing graphical login. Please help.